# Different classloaders cause ClassCastException when persisting data via Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, classloader, jdo

I'm creating an MVC Spring webapp. 
Using: Jetty (servlet container), DataNucleus (dao platform), DB4O (embedded datastore).

When I persist an object (done from within a Spring Controller) using JDO from DataNucleus, it stores to the DB fine.

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class Test {
    @Persistent
    private String testString;
    //getter-setters implemented
}
```

When I do a simple query for the objects I previously added I get a `ClassCastException` on my Test class (can't cast `a.b.c.Test` to `a.b.c.Test`).

The classloader of Test returned by JDO is (toString) `[sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5acac268]`, the classloader of the Test class before I persisted it to the DB is `[WebAppClassLoader@1593275665]`

I've gotten this far, but I don't really know what to do with a classloader issue like this, I've never spent much thought on classloaders before. Any direction is helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't need to be two different versions of the class for a class cast exception to appear. **Even the same class definition is seen as two different classes when loaded by two distinct classloaders.** Which seems to be the case here.

Unfortunately I am not familiar with the platforms you use, so I can't give more concrete advice than this: try to experiment with moving the jar containing your `Test` class to different places on your web app classpath, and/or reconfiguring the Spring and Jetty classloaders so that both delegate the loading of `Test` to the same parent classloader.

Answer (score 2):

I think that your problem might be similar to the one described [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/jdo-dev@db.apache.org/msg02840.html).

If so, the cure would appear to be to make sure that the jdo jarfile is loaded by a common ancestor of the classloaders.